# VB code for VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel

I'm completely new to VBA. I tried recording a macro of using VLOOKUP function in my spreadsheet, but turns out VLOOKUP recorded like that does not work.

I have a working spreadsheet and I am comparing values in the column "Material" with a different workbook that is like a database for all the materials and their respective programs. The program the material number matches to in the database will be recorded under column "Program" in the working spreadsheet. I use VLOOKUP to do this, but I am having a hard time coming up with a macro for it.

As suggested, I did the following:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "'Program"

Range("K41").Select

ActiveCell.Formula = "VLOOKUP(D41,"'C:\Users\Username\Desktop[Database.xlsx]Sheet1!R1C1:R152289C4,4,FALSE)"
```

But it still does not populate the "Program" column. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the code you recorded and explain what "does not work" about it?

Comment: Why do you need a macro to create a Vlookup? Why not just copy and paste the formula to the cells where it is needed?

Comment: @teylyn This is going to be implemented in a system that automates everyday, hence the need for a macro.

Comment: What error do you get? What happens when you manually enter that formula into a cell to test if it returns anything? Why are you mixing absolute and relative cell references?

Answer (score 0):

The exact line for vlookups can be done in two ways;

1) This does a vlookup within the coding environment, it's more difficult to make it dynamic

```
application.worksheetfunction.vlookup(worksheets("Material").range("A2"), worksheets("Program").range("A1:F10"),4,0)
```

2) Make the formula in the cell the vlookup

```
range("c2").select
activecell.formula = "=vlookup(A1,Material!A1:F10,4,0)"
```

and then use the environment to fill in.

Maudise

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need this spreadsheet to be dynamic. So if i'm using the second formula, and my database is in a different workbook, do I just paste the file path for the file and the name of the worksheet in place of "Material" (please see my edit above)?

Comment: @maudise, .Select is hardly ever required. Using it in such a situation is bad practice or lack of experience.

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to all who took the time to address my question. I took suggestions, played around with the formula, and this is what I got:

=VLOOKUP($D41,'C:\Users\Username\Desktop[Database.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$A$1:$B$40973,2,FALSE)

Does exactly what I wanted it to do! Thanks again!